# System.LimitException: Maximum stack depth reached: 3 in sending mail as community user

Tags: apex, trigger, email-template, community

The problem is that the below trigger works perfectly for System Administrator but does not work for the community user.I have tries checking various permissions.BP_NotificationSupportTeamMember this is a visualforce template in this  display details of the case

```
public with sharing class CaseTriggerHelper {

    // Varibale to check whether to run case trigger or not 
    public static boolean runTrigger = true;

    // List to store Cases of trigger.new
    public static List<Case> newCasesList = new List<Case>();
    // List to store Cases of trigger.old
    public static List<Case> oldCasesList = new List<Case>();
    // Map to store Cases of trigger.newMap
    public static Map<Id, Case> newCasesMap = new Map<Id, Case>();
    // Map to store Cases of trigger.oldMap
    public static Map<Id, Case> oldCasesMap = new Map<Id, Case>();

    //Sending Mail for  Support Team Member
    public static void sendMailForNotificationSupportTeamMember(){
        List<Network> networkObjectList = [Select id,EmailSenderAddress from Network];
        String subject = 'Case ' +newCasesList[0].CaseNumber + ' New Case';
        list<EmailTemplate> templateList_notificationsupportTeamMember = new list<EmailTemplate>([Select IsActive,ApiVersion,Body,MarkUp,HtmlValue,Id From EmailTemplate  WHERE Name ='BP_NotificationSupportTeamMember']);
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        System.debug(newCasesList[0].ownerId + 'newCasesList[0].ownerId');
        List<User> userList = [Select id,ContactId from User where id=: newCasesList[0].ownerId];
        for(Case caseRecord : newCasesList)
        {
            //Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            // Step 2: Set list of people who should get the email
            List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
            sendTo.add(networkObjectList[0].EmailSenderAddress);
            // Step 3: Set who the email is sent from
            mail.setReplyTo(networkObjectList[0].EmailSenderAddress);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('XYZ');
            System.debug(userList[0].id + 'userList[0].id');
            mail.setTargetObjectId(userList[0].id);
            mail.setWhatId(caseRecord.id);
            mail.setTemplateId(templateList_notificationsupportTeamMember.get(0).id);

            // (Optional) Set list of people who should be CC'ed

            // Step 4. Set email contents - you can use variables!
          //  mail.setSubject(subject);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            System.debug(templateList_notificationsupportTeamMember.get(0));
            mails.add(mail);

        }
        try{
           Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
           mails.clear();
        }
        catch(LimitException ex){
            System.debug(ex);

         } 
    }
    //Sending Mail for Acknowledgment Support Request
    public static void sendMailForAcknowledgmentSupportRequest(){
        List<Network> networkObjectList = [Select id,EmailSenderAddress from Network];
        String subject = 'Case ' +newCasesList[0].CaseNumber + ' -Thanks for contacting support';
    // Retrieving Email template  
        list<EmailTemplate> templateList_notificationsupportTeamMember = new list<EmailTemplate>([Select IsActive,ApiVersion,Body,MarkUp,HtmlValue,Id From EmailTemplate  WHERE Name =: 'BP_HTMLEmail acknowledging Support Request']);
        List<Messaging.MassEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.MassEmailMessage>();
        List<User> userList = [Select id,ContactId,Email  from User where id=: newCasesList[0].ownerId];
        for(Case caseRecord : newCasesList)
        {
            //Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);
            Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();

            // Step 3: Set who the email is sent from
            mail.setReplyTo(networkObjectList[0].EmailSenderAddress);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('BlackPurl Admin');
            System.debug(userList[0].id + 'userList[0].id');
            mail.setTargetObjectIds(new List<Id>{userList[0].id});
            System.debug(caseRecord.id + 'caseRecord.id');
mail.setTemplateId(templateList_notificationsupportTeamMember.get(0).id);

            // (Optional) Set list of people who should be CC'ed

            // Step 4. Set email contents - you can use variables!
          //  mail.setSubject(subject);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            System.debug(templateList_notificationsupportTeamMember.get(0));
            mails.add(mail);

        }
        try{
           Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
           mails.clear();
        }
        catch(LimitException ex){
            System.debug(ex);

         }
    }

}
```

//THis is the  trigger

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert) {
     // Assign values of trigger new list to helper class variable
    CaseTriggerHelper.newCasesList = trigger.new;

    // Assign values of trigger old list to helper class variable
    CaseTriggerHelper.oldCasesList = trigger.old;

    // Assign values of trigger new map to helper class variable
    CaseTriggerHelper.newCasesMap = trigger.newMap;

    // Assign values of trigger old map to helper class variable
    CaseTriggerHelper.oldCasesMap = trigger.oldMap;

    System.debug(CaseTriggerHelper.runTrigger + 'CaseTriggerHelper.runTrigger');
    // To run trigger if to run trigger or not
    if(CaseTriggerHelper.runTrigger) {

        if(trigger.isAfter) {
            if(trigger.isInsert) {
                CaseTriggerHelper.sendMailForNotificationSupportTeamMember();
                CaseTriggerHelper.sendMailForAcknowledgmentSupportRequest();
            }
        }
    }       

}
```